# Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/amasty_paction/template/grid/tree-massactions.html Magento 2

Tags: magento2, massaction

I have installed Amasty Mass product action extension for Magento 2.When i enabled that extension product grid does not load in the backend.
Please check below Screenshot,

[image]

I have checked log file and i got below error in my log file,

**[2019-05-08 07:00:21] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/amasty_paction/template/grid/tree-massactions.html' [] []**

Can anyone help me?